# Downloading Initial App Data

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

When a user opens the app, it needs to download information stored on a MySQL database, save it to Core Data, then display it in a table view controller. The download and saving of the data works, but not presenting it to the user. The data doesn't present itself the first time the view controller is displayed; it presents itself only after switching to a different view and returning. I have tried putting the code which loads the data in the viewWillAppear function (where I think it belongs) and the viewDidLoad function -- both with the same, previously described outcome. Can someone help spot what I may be doing wrong? Maybe I have the statements executing in the wrong order?

Also, another weird thing I see is when I run it in the debugger or with breakpoints (aka when I give the app more time to load), it works fine. It's only on a normal run when I have these problems.

---

**View Did Load**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    /*This is where I would put the code to load the data. See the first 
    part of viewWillAppear too see what the code is.*/
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"viewWillAppear:", name:
        UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
}
```

**View Will Appear**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if(!defaults.boolForKey("objectivesDownloaded")) {
        downloadObjectives()
        defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "objectivesDownloaded")
    }
    defaults.synchronize()
    fetchObjectives()
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

**Fetch Objectives**

```
func fetchObjectives() {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Objective")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "logIndex", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    var error: NSError?
    let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as [NSManagedObject]?
    if var results = fetchedResults {
        objectives = results
    } else {
        println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I assume that `downloadObjectives` is an asynchrounus background task, meaning that `fetchObjectives` is already called when `downloadObjectives` is still working.

Comment: I don't know enough to confirm or deny that. Is there away I can code it so it downloads the objectives then load that view? Would I put the code to download it in the `applicationDidBecomeActive()` or `applicationWillEnterForeground()` functions in AppDelegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user has to login before seeing the main view, so I added the download code in the login script after it finds the login successful, but before the view controller is presented. The data now displays on start.

```
if(loginSucceeded) {
    self.downloadObjectives()
    self.defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "objectivesDownloaded")
    let tabBarController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabBarController") as UIViewController
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
        self.presentViewController(tabBarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you probably aren't telling your table to reload data after you fetch your data. (it would initially load with no data when your view loads)

i.e. in obj-c

```
[yourTable reloadData]
```

swift

```
yourTable.reloadData()
```

Comment: So, I deleted the app and restarted this, and it still doesn't download objectives right away. I have included `tableView.reloadData()`. Any other suggestions?